# How to, dynamically disable or enable a ng-multiselect-dropdown in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, getelementbyid

template

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown #Name [placeholder]="'Name'" [data]="data" 
    formControlName="name" [settings]="myNameTexts"(onDeSelectAll)="onNameDeSelect($this)"> 
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

component

```
 document.getElementById("#Name").disabled= false
```

Comment: // in HTML : 

 <ng-multiselect-dropdown #Name
    [placeholder]="'Name'"
    [data]="data"
    formControlName="name"
    [settings]="myNameTexts"
    (onDeSelectAll)="onNameDeSelect($this)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are use reactive forms you can disable any form control by he disable method of the from control like this

```
this.form.get('name').disable()
```

it 'is look like the author doesn't implement control accessor interface correctly in case you try to set the disabled property in the template ,while it will work but you will got a warning

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true when you set up this control in
>   your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in
>   the DOM for you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed
>   after checked' errors.
>
> Example:  form = new FormGroup({ first: new FormControl({value:
>   'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required), last: new
>   FormControl('Drew', Validators.required) });

this just work around this bug so to keep the disable value base of the form control we can you disabled property base of the form control disable value

component

```
  get disabled() {
    return this.myForm.get('city').disable
  }
```

template

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <ng-multiselect-dropdown
            name="city"
            [placeholder]="'Select City'"
            [data]="cities"
            formControlName="city"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [settings]="dropdownSettings"
            (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)">
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
   </form>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hw8ugk)

Answer (score 3):

Should be more like:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [disabled]="isDropdownDisabled" ...> 
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

and in control:

```
public isDropdownDisabled = false;

someMethod() {
  this.isDropdownDisabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I already did that but I don't like it , because you will get warning message in the control , the author of this library does not implement control accessor interface correctly

Comment: Is this the one you're using https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/blob/master/src/ng-multiselect-dropdown/src/multiselect.component.ts ? I don't get what the problem is...

Comment: whebn you are using reactive form any change on the form control will reflect to the component automatickly like disable but in here there is a bug check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hw8ugk

Comment: this `this.form.get('name').disable()` should make the component as disabled without set the property in the template

Comment: @malbarmawi in that case you should pass disabled via the form control like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auupgp?file=src/app/app.component.ts That's not a bug with that control, it's because of your code since you are using the reactive forms approach

Comment: the problem is this `[disabled]="disabled"` we not supposed to do it , this related to the library it self

Comment: In that case you have 2 options: fork the component and fix it and use that private fork or create a pull request and hope the author accepts the change. It should be a pretty simple change, just a new line of code :) I see there's also an open issue: https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues/144

Comment: Thanks. This helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
disabled="true"
```

It will disable your dropdown.

Comment: I mean dynamicaly, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS property 'pointer-events: none' on your control.

Comment: @codowo was asking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: Yes, we can add style/classes dynamically too.